# SharePoint 2013 Patching: Missing patches

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching

From Central admin, we find few missing patches under "Check product and Patch installation status "

From Those missing patches, few belong to Dec 18 CU and few belong to Jan 19 CU.

When installing them, do i need to patch twice with Dec CU and Jan CU or Jan 19 CU will cover everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan 2019 CU should include all the fixes from the Dec 2018 CU. You only need to install the Jan 2019 CU to patch it fully. Please dont forget to run the PSConfig wizard at the end on each server.

[January 2019 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2019/01/08/january-2019-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)